# Set header using scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: scrlayer-scrpage

I would like the section to be displayed in the header using `\automark`. However, if a chapter does not include a section I would like the chapter to be diplayed in the header.

How do I achieve that?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,headsepline,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead[]{\pagemark}
\automark[]{section}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\blindtext[10]

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\blindtext[12]

\section{Section 1}

\blindtext[14]

\chapter{Chapter 3}

\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is also a starred version of `\automark`.

From the [scrguien.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf):

> The difference in `\automark` and `\automark*` is, that `\automark` deletes all prior usages of `\automark` or `\automark*`, while `\automark*` changes only the behaviour of the section levels of its arguments.

Using

```
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark{chapter}
\automark*{section}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}
```

the chapter is displayed in the header as long as the first section appears.

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,headsepline,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark{chapter}
\automark*{section}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}

\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\blindtext[10]
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\blindtext[12]
\section{Section 1}
\blindtext[14]
\chapter{Chapter 3}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

In a single-sided document, a `\section` command doesn't issue a `\markright`. So, add the following lines in your preamble

```
\renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{%
    \markright{\MakeMarkcase{\ifnumbered{section}{\sectionmarkformat}{}#1}}%
}
```

Also delete the line

```
\automark[]{section}
```

and load `scrlayer-scrpage` with the `automark` option.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,headsepline,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}

\renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{%
    \markright{\MakeMarkcase{\ifnumbered{section}{\sectionmarkformat}{}#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\blindtext[10]

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\blindtext[12]

\section{Section 1}

\blindtext[14]

\chapter{Chapter 3}

\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

[image]